# Prove that p → □p is not derivable in system K?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

The only way I could think of doing this is to show that p → □p with the K axioms would imply a contradiction, but I don't think that's true. Not sure how to get started on this. Do I just have to construct a possible countermodel?

Comment: No.  A statement not being theorem *does not* mean that it is a contradiction.  You would merely have to show that it is a contingency.

Comment: Constructing a countermodel using Kripke semantics would seem to be the best way to go.

Comment: I recommend you to ponder over this question further; it would lead you to an illuminating debate on the availability of a deduction theorem in modal logic. See R. Hakli and S. Negri's 2012 paper "Does the Deduction Theorem Fail for Modal Logic?" Synthese 187, pp. 849-867.